# Update View while in different perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I came across a small problem while developing my eclipse RCP application which is based on the 3.x API.
I have two different perspective, in one there are a lot of tree viewers and in the other is one tree viewer and one editor. The problem is when I'm in my first perspective and I start the traversing process, which takes a long time and runs in a background process, I want in the meanwhile switch to the second perspective to do some working. After a while the traversing finishes, I'm still in my second perspective, and want to update all the tree viewers in my first perspective, but the problem is how do I get the corresponding view instance to perform the update? I can only access the active page but this doesn't help me.
So is there a way to access the view from the first perspective while I'm still in the second perspective? If not what else could I do to solve this problem?
One solution I could devise is to save the result from the traversing and wait until I change back to my first perspective and then do the updating, but this would mean that I need some class that temporarily saves my result which is kind of very large.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You have access to all the workbench pages, `IWorkbenchWindow` has a `getPages()` method.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks I didn't know about that getPages() in IWorkbenchWindow ... I'll try it out tomorrow 

Comment: @greg-449 I just tried it out but it still doesn't work ... I used the following method to get all my workbench windows but I only get one although two windows are open: `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();`

Comment: @greg-449 When I go into this one page I can find all my views also the views from my other perspective, but it seems that when I call the function 'findView(...)' it only goes through the views from the current perspective but not those from the other perspective ... Why is that so ... Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the tree viewer to be updated to the background process when you start it rather than trying to find the view again?

Comment: @greg-449 Hmm yes, but then I need to pass more than 10 different tree viewers to this background process ... And what happens if the user closes the perspective during the traversing process ... Can I somehow check if the view is still open?

Comment: Call `isDisposed()` in the `Tree` in the tree viewer to see if it has been closed.

Comment: @greg-449 Hmm doesn't work for me ... The background process is a command and is called when the user double-click on a element in the first tree viewer ... But the other views which display the result don't even exists at this time and so I cannot pass the tree viewer to the background process